# Why does break terminate the whole program and not just the current thread

Tags: c#, concurrency

I was reading about BlockingCollection (a specific example of concurrent collections) and came across this small program that demonstrates how they work. This program doubles my input (whatever I type is doubled when I press enter), and it goes on like this until I input a space.

My question is why doesn't the program block on the first line "while(true)" ?

My guess is that BlockingCollection blocks the read Task when there is no element to remove from the collection, so I suppose it's freed again once col.Add(s) happens, because an element becomes available.

Secondly, when a whitespace is entered, why isn't just the current thread stopped (the one with the write Task)? Shouldn't the read task continue to wait for an unblocker forever? Instead the whole program is terminated.

```
public static class ConcurrentCollections
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        BlockingCollection<string> col = new BlockingCollection<string>();

        Task read = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(col.Take());
            }
        });
        Task write = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string s = Console.ReadLine();
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)) break;
                col.Add(s);
            }
        });
        write.Wait();

          Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: To answer one of your questions: All threads create lives in the context of the process. If the process die, all threads dies. So when the write task is completed because of the whitespace and the `write.Wait()` continues and goes out of the `Main`method, the application/process is terminated and so is all threads. You can of course argue if you find this nice or not. Also remember that you have 3 threads in this application; the main  thread, and `read`and `write` threads.

Comment: In addition to the answers, note that the tasks are running in **background** threads. If you were running the code from your `read` task in a **foreground** thread (possible by using the `System.Threading.Thread` class), it would prevent your application process from ending until the `read` thread ends (a process ends if _all_ foreground threads have exited). See also here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.isbackground?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why doesn't the program block on the first line "while(true)" ?

Because it's running in a separate thread. Both `read` and `write` run on their own threads, separate from the main thread.

> when a whitespace is entered, why isn't just the current thread stopped (the one with the write Task)?

The current thread is the `write` thread. It does end. But notice this:

```
write.Wait();
```

This tells the main thread to wait for the `write` thread. But notice that it does not wait for the `read` thread. So as soon as the `write` thread ends, the main thread moves on to the `Console.ReadLine()`, which waits for the enter key. And as soon as you press enter, the main thread ends, which means the whole application ends.

The `read` thread is left open the whole time, but when the main thread ends, the process is terminated, which kills the `read` thread too.

Comment: Thank a lot, but I still don't understand all the details e.g. 
why if I write `write.Wait()` I see my input is copied on the output however many times UNTIL I press enter, but if I don't write `write.Wait()` my input is copied just once, then the program ends?

Comment: `write.Wait()` tells the main thread to wait until the `write` thread is done. The `write` thread is what is calling `Console.WriteLine()`, which is the output you see.

Comment: If you take out `write.Wait()` then the main thread doesn't wait for anything and just finishes. When the main thread finishes, the application terminates, even if there are other threads doing something.

Comment: The write thread is what is calling Console.WriteLine(), which is the output I see? But the Console.WriteLine() is in the read thread, not the write thread. How would you explain this?

Comment: Right, sorry. The `read` thread calls `Console.WriteLine()`(it "reads" from there `BlockingCollection`).

Comment: And the reason why it comes back to read after doing the write thread is because read was paused/blocked for not being able to remove an element from a collection that had none, and as soon as the element is added on line `col.Add(s);` the control is rendered back to thread read? What if there was additional code after `col.Add(s)` in write, would control still be rendered to read immediately or after the rest of the code in write was consumed?

Comment: I think maybe the right way to put it is that immediately after col.Add(s) is performed the read thread is unblocked and the two threads begin to run concurrently, with the read thread being blocked again each time there is nothing to remove. How about that??

Comment: Yes, your second comment is more accurate. There is no "control" being passed back and forth - the two threads run concurrently.